# Comparing column values of two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I am rather new to Python and I saw someone compare columns of two different DFs like this but i am getting the following error:

Error: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

My code:

```
df1["PC"] = np.where(np.logical_and(df1["MPG"].isnull(),df1["MC"] == df2["MC"]),
                                              df2["PC"],'Unassigned')
```

To explain the snippet, I am trying to update the PC column in DF1 where the MPG column is null and df1[MC] == df2[MC], if the condition matches, update PC Column in DF1 with the value in DF2.

DF2:

| PC | MC |
| --- | --- |
| PC1 | MC1 |
| PC2 | MC2 |
| PC3 | MC3 |
| PC4 | MC4 |

DF1:

| PC | MPG | MC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PC2 | MPG2 | MC2 |
|  |  | MC1 |
| PC1 | MPG1 | MC1 |
|  |  | MC3 |

EXPECTED RESULT OF ABOVE CODE:

DF1:

| PC | MPG | MC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PC2 | MPG2 | MC2 |
| PC1 |  | MC1 |
| PC1 | MPG1 | MC1 |
| PC3 |  | MC3 |

Please let me know if you have any questions.

EDIT: My df1 has alot more columns that i am not showing here. I specifically want to update the PC column only.

Thanks,

Waleed

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print(df1[df1["PC"].isin(df2["PC"])])
```

This will check if the values for the column `PC` in `df1` are present in the `df2` and will merge them accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have a few questions. I want to target a specific column of DF1 to update. I dont want to merge two dfs. in this case, i only want to update df1[PC] column with the values found in df2[PC] column if df1[MPG] is null and df1[MC] == df2[MC]. So how do i only update that one column?